# angular 2 + jee7 (wildfly)

Tags: angular, authorization, wildfly, jaas

this is my response from WF

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Expires: 0
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
X-Powered-By: Undertow/1
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=IQCjYqZ4Vy06q072fdIR6a41.sk-za-04702; path=/prototype-rest
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: accept, authorization, content-type, x-requested-with
Server: WildFly/8
Pragma: no-cache
Date: Thu, 03 Nov 2016 09:33:07 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Access- Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Content-Length: 0
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT
Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600
```

angular 2 represent this reponse as error -> I've added all possible cors to WF, still no idea where is problem.

Comment: There is a space here `Access- Control-Allow-Origin`

Comment: many thanks !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! ... solved

Comment: Glad i could help!

Answer (score 2):

Apparently the problem is the space in the `Access- Control-Allow-Origin: *` header.

Just putting it here.. well.. so this question can have an answer :)